# Android resources compilation failed why this is showing

Tags: java, android

**Here is the .xml file** what  was the error here...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Subject">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:hint="Message">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="send">

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> After that it shows me Android Resources compilations failed... and
> AAPT: error: not well-formed (invalid token)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close your tags properly with `/>`,
your xml code should be below from linear layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">



    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="Subject"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="Message"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="send"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes It is showing due to lack of closing tag...</EditText> and </Button>
Thanks Buddy...

Comment: Welcome buddy and hey if this answer  helps you should accept or upvote the answer , thanks